# Using Turn.js in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, blocks, third-party-module

I would like to have a section on my product page where customers can view my products using Turn.js (if there are any other similar plugins let me know!). I currently have an empty block setup. 
[image]

Is there a way to implement turn.js into that block? The end goal is to upload a couple of images for each one of my products and have it displayed there.

If you need more information feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up created a custom module where my xml layout (catalog_product_view.xml)

```
<referenceBlock name="content">
    <block class="custom\module\Block\Product\Downloads" name="downloads.tab" as="downloads"
           template="custom_module::downloads.phtml"
           after="product.info.media"
           before="product.info.details">
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

then I added turn.js plugin

created a js file flipbook.js

web>js>turn.js

web>js>flipbook.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Sebwite_ProductDownloads/js/turn'
], function($) {
    'use strict'
      var module = {

    init: function(id) {
      var me = this;


      // if older browser then don't run javascript
      if (document.addEventListener) {
        this.el = document.getElementById(id);
        this.resize();
        this.plugins();

        // on window resize, update the plugin size
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
          var size = me.resize();
          $(me.el).turn('size', size.width, size.height)
        });
      }
    },
    resize: function() {
      // reset the width and height to the css defaults
      this.el.style.width = '';
      this.el.style.height = '';


      var ratio = 2;
      var f = $('.swatch-attribute-selected-option')[0].innerHTML;
      console.log(f)

        switch(f) {
          case 'Square Hardback':
          ratio = 2;
          break;
          case 'Standard Softback':
          case 'Large Softback':
          case 'Large Hardback':
          ratio = 1.5;
          break;
          case 'Landscape Hardback':
          ratio = 2.66;
          break;
          default: 
          ratio = 2;
        }

      var width = this.el.clientWidth,
        height = Math.round(width / ratio),
        padded = Math.round(document.body.clientHeight * 0.9);

      // if the height is too big for the window, constrain it
      if (height > padded) {
        height = padded;
        width = Math.round(height * ratio);
      }
      // set the width and height matching the aspect ratio
      this.el.style.width = width + 'px';
      this.el.style.height = height + 'px';

      return {
        width: width,
        height: height
      };
    },
    plugins: function() {
      // run the plugin
      $(this.el).turn({
        gradients: true,
        acceleration: true,
        duration: 2000
      });
    }
  };

  module.init('book');
});
```

Then create

templates>downloads.phtml

and ran a `<php foreach($download as $x); ?>`
to loop through all my images I uploaded